# rake seed_fu for test env fails because of 'undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass' in factory for object that should be seeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, seeding

I need to seed my test-database (MySQL, with [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) library). I'm using [seed_fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) gem for seeding. My tests are in [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec) and test-data is made with the help of [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).

I have made a custom rake task inside `lib/tasks/db.rake` for seeding **only** my test-database like this:

```
namespace :db do

  desc "Seed_fu only in test-database"
  task seed_fu_test: :environment do
    puts "Seeding will be made in test-base ONLY!"
    SeedFu.fixture_paths = "/home/me/developments/myapp/db/fixtures/test"
    system("rake db:seed_fu RAILS_ENV=test")
  end
end
```

**Problem:** When running `rake db:seed_fu_test` I get:

> rake aborted!
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
>   /home/me/developments/myapp/spec/factories/mymodel_factory.rb:16:in`block (3 levels) in '

`mymodel_factory.rb:16` looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :mymodel do
    attr1 "first"
    attr2 "second"
    # ...

    trait :other_alternative do
      alternative_type_id AlternativeType.find_by(name: "other").id # Line 16 -> HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
      template TemplateText.find_by(name: "Teenusleping")
    end
  end
end
```

I don't understand why seeding process needs to check the factories at all? I mean- you can use factories only when your database is ready, that means the seeding should be done before. At the moment `AlternativeType` is the table that would be seeded and the error therefore seems kind of pointless to me.

**EDIT** [Here](http://pastebin.com/ycThj2Vr) is my rspec rails_helper and [here](http://pastebin.com/g77mXPSc) is the spec_helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's a precedence issue: FactoryGirl seems to be loaded when you are launching your app in the `test` environment, and this is done before the seeding takes place.

I would ensure that `factory_girl` is loaded only by `RSpec` when launching your specs.

EDIT: It turned out to be an issue related to Bundler.

```
group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Here, `Bundler` will automatically load `FactoryGirl` whenever we are in the `test` environment. We need to tell it to not require it automatically:

```
group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', require: false
end
```

Later on, you'll also need to add the `require factory_girl_rails` to your `rails_helper` for your spec to use `FactoryGirl`.

Comment: How can I ensure this? I believe in my rspec-folder the rails_helper.rb and spec_helper.rb are the issue, but so far I haven't managed to fix the problem by testing with those files.

Comment: Make a global search on your project to see where you actually initialize factorygirl. It should only be when using rspec (indeed `rails_helper` and `spec_helper`) is launched. For instance, if you were to do `bundle exec rails console -e test`, it should not load `factory girl`, nor `rspec`.

Comment: Global search showed that the only place where I initialize factory_girl is in my spec_helper with `require 'factory_girl_rails'` and in `RSpec.configure`-block with `config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods`. Even commenting factory_girl out from there didn't make any difference.

Comment: Could you please post your `rails_helper` and `spec_helper`?

Comment: Sure- I added links to my rails_helper and spec_helper. See the edit in the question.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you, by any chance, load folders in your `application.rb` or your `test.rb`?

Comment: Nope- checked it and didn't see anything that could affect this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108906/discussion-between-andres-ehrenpreis-and-born4new).